# merge divs for different elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to do that bootstrap model:[image]

But the alignement isn't working well because there's a dropdown list (It's not all elements of the same type).
This is what I came for:
[image]

This is my fiddle:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control label">Prefix:</label><br />
                        <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
                            <select name="prefix" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">  
                <div class="row">   
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="suffix">Suffix:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="suffix" name="suffix">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="info">Information:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="info" name="info"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this alignment problem?

Comment: possibly you forgot some class to add. Is there 'form-control' class in dropdown ?

Comment: can you please add your code

Comment: if adding css class isn't working out, consider using a table for such strict alignment. Always works like a charm for me!

Comment: @dulajsanjaya question edited

Comment: @HariHarker table is an old way my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: http://www.bootply.com/TvgQizWRZw

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <label for="prefix">Prefix</label>
           <select name="prefix" class="form-control" id="prefix">
             <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
             <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
             <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
           </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="tbLastName">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbLastName">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="tbFirstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbFirstName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="tbSuffix">Suffix</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbSuffix">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="tbInfo">Information</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" id="tbInfo">Test</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but why inserting a global column inside the row ? Can't we fix this without the big col-md-8 ?

Comment: @JohnyNassar not sure if I understand what is meant by "big column". You can always change `col-md-8` to `col-xs-8` if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean that you divided the row into 2 column (col-md-8 and col-md-4), I divided it into 3 equal columns. Can't we fix the alignment by using 3 columns instead of 2?

Comment: @JohnyNassar that's only because content of the `col-md-8` is divided to two lines/rows (as your layout screenshots shows). In fact these are 3 equal columns. If you divide the `col-md-8` on two halfs you get the same result as they would be in one row with 3 equal columns. There isn't difference. The `col-md-8` represents the 66.66% of entire width. If you divide this into two halfs what you get relatively to the parent? 33.33% as it would be in 3 equal columns.

Comment: I did understand that those are the same mathematically. If those are the same, how did you fix the alignment issue?

Comment: @JohnyNassar your solution has many flaws. Columns are not always immediate children of rows, they don't alwyas fit the full 12 columns and so on. Please carefully read the official documentation on grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid the `Introduction` section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118403/discussion-between-johny-nassar-and-ivan-sivak).

Comment: ok I know that columns aren't always immediate children of rows but my alignment was incorrect for the reason that there's a dropdown list in it?
cause if all the element are text this issue will not appear anymore
right?